# Has Charles Xavier ever exhibited the ability to freeze minds/time in the comics?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men

In the *X-Men* movies, Professor Charles Xavier exhibits the ability to freeze minds, effectively stopping time for people on a fairly large scale, freezing everyone in the Oval Office and an entire food court full of people in *X-2: X-Men United*.

When the movie was released, many fans were surprised/confused at this apparent new power.

**Has this ability ever been exhibited by Charles Xavier in the comics before, or since?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In *Giant-Size X-Men #1*, in Nightcrawler's first appearance, a Bavarian mob is about to murder him when...

[image: Professor X stops the Bavarian mod from murdering Nightcrawler]

Comment: @Beta- Good call to kick it ole school!

Answer (score 7):

The entry for Marvel Movies Wiki entry on [Charles Xavier](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Charles_Xavier#Powers) lists one power as

> **Paralyzation:** He can mentally paralyze others, **making it appear as if time has been stopped.**

The Marvel Wiki entry for [Charles Xavier](http://marvel.wikia.com/Charles_Xavier_%28Earth-616%29#Powers) has this power listed

> **Mind Control:** ability to control the minds of others upon mere concentration. This power can allow him to completely shut down several people's minds, **making it appear as if time has stopped.**

That is the entry for Earth-616, which is the primary continuity for the comics. This means he has this ability in the comics as well.

Comment: But has it ever actually used it in comics, or has he just been described as being able to?