# Has a telepathic character in DC Comics been able to telepathically freeze people/time like Professor X in Marvel?

Tags: dc, telepathy, mind-control, telekinesis

Since it has been established that Professor X has been shown to use his telepathic/telekinetic powers to mentally halt people in their tracks in both comics and the movies - see [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/57208/has-charles-xavier-ever-exhibited-the-ability-to-freeze-minds-time-in-the-comics) for that - my question simply asks if any telepathic characters in the DC Universe (Martian Manhunter, Manchester Black, etc.) showed something similar.

Comment: Do spores/vegetables/any plant thingy count? It's indirect mind control, but Poison Ivy does that sometimes.

Comment: First place I'd look is the Legion of Super-Heroes - Saturn Girl and villain Universo would both be candidates, I think.

Comment: Tried that but the closest ability I see them doing is hypnosis. I'm asking about mentally freezing people so they don't move just like what Professor X can do

Answer (score 2):

This is not a common power in the DC universe.  However, there is:

## Praxis.

[image: Praxis]

<sub>Seen here in his debut, *Spectre* Vol. 2 Issue 24.</sub>

Jason Praxis is a police detective and powerful telepath. One of his [abilities](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/praxis/4005-10111/) is inducing "temporary mental or physical paralysis," and can [also](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Jason_Praxis_(New_Earth)) render someone unconscious-- both handy powers for tracking down criminals! (He's an obscure character, so I couldn't find any relevant comic panels.)